# Cloud backup with specific requirements

Tags: backup, cloud

First of all, I'm aware of threads like [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools).

With that in mind, I have a specific set of requirements for backup, and I was wondering which are the current options - the informations around are fragmented and confusing, especially considering that **online drives are not backup solutions**.

My requirements are the following:

- be able to backup individual files (ie. no dejadup, thanks)
- cloud storage (upload of an intermediate backup archive is not viable)
- have a daemon running in the background, backing up at least at time intervals (optionally, having a continuous backup)
- no need to setup a server
- file versioning
- ability to handle large data sets (number of files rather than space)
- ability to backup drives that are not guaranteed to be mounted, without hassles

Optionally:

- restore from the backup structure of a given point in time. this is different from restoring from the current backup tree, with the option of choosing older versions.
- reporting

Price doesn't matter.

Excluded solutions:

- JungleDisk was perfect, until the moment it's been discontinued.
- SpiderOak is really badly coded; It has annoying bugs, and it hangs on large number of files. Also, if a drive is not mounted when SO starts, it won't be backed up.
- Symform has a bug in the registration. Since you can't contact support without registering, it's completely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about minimal setup, but otherwise CrashPlan should meet your requirements. Actually CrashPlans setup is anything but minimal. :(

Comment: until now, Crashplan looks a viable choice. I've corrected the question as you pointed with a more appropriate wording (I didn't want to setup a server, essentially).

Comment: Note that Crashplan is also poorly coded, and will fill your root directory with backup files if you ever have a [destination drive unmounted](http://askubuntu.com/a/17652/12864) when it wants to write, or if you use an [encrypted /home](http://askubuntu.com/a/182878/12864) (it runs before you login and can mount /home). Avoid.

Comment: @TomBrossman Does this hold even if home has been encrypted as part of the Ubuntu-installation?

Comment: @Konstantin Correct. If you have an encrypted `/home` directory, you can't use Crashplan. You might try to fix the bug yourself, or come up with a workaround. It's a commercial product and other superior products exist so I went elsewhere.

Comment: @TomBrossman can you elaborate on the superior products? That's what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: @Konstantin you can install CrashPlan for your user only. This way, it will start after you login, so that it will be able to handle an encrypted home.

Comment: @Marcus Thank you, that's how I was using it and I was surprised because I had never encountered that problem. So, the takeaway is: If you install it for each user seperately, it will be launched after login and work fine?